# Accessing Folders / Files Outside of the webroot but still within the app path?

Tags: cakephp, file-access

I have a folder within the app of my site, `data`, that is not within the web root. This is done for extra security so only certain people will have access to it. The code I have used, from looking at the CakePHP docs is as follows:

```
foreach($ImageToSort as $FileDisplayKey => $FileDisplayData) {
    $FileName = $ImageToSort[$FileDisplayKey]['Fileinfo']['filename'];
    $WholePathName = 'data/'.$FileName;
}

$this->response->file($WholePathName);
return $this->response;
```

It loads the file but not within my view (the above code is in a view, `$ImageToSort` is set from a find call within my Controller).

So how can I load files that do not sit within the webroot with a loop of some sort, so I can view them and place them on my site in the way I choose?

PS. I CAN NOT put the files within the webroot folder as someone only needs to know the name for the file for them to be able to get it. Access to these files needs to be keep to a select few.

Many thanks for any help given,

Glenn

**UPDATE:**

I am using 2.4 and from what I read media views are not what I should be using but 'sending files' are the calls that have replaced them. I have tried to use them with the following code:

```
$this->viewClass = 'Media';

$params = array(
    'id'        => $FileName,
    'name'      => 'example',
    'extension' => 'jpg',
    'path'      => APP . 'uploads/test' . DS
);

$this->set($params);

debug($params['id']);
$name = $params['id'];
$path = $params['path'];
$filename = $path.$name;


//echo 'name::' .$name;
echo "<img src=";
echo $filename;
echo ">";
```

This can not find the file unless I place the file into `/webroot/data/test`, and then it displays it fine. But that is just completely pointless? I need only selected users to view selected files for security issues.

The following code does work in viewing the file within the `/app/data/test` path,

```
$this->autoRender = false;
$this->response->file(Configure::read('uploads').$WholePathName);
```

But this code makes no difference when used in a controller or view, it still only displays the file and no layout or styles or title or anything. Again, this is completely pointless.

There must be a way where I can keep my files access and read the files/folders I need.

Glenn

Comment: Have a look into http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/media-view.html

Comment: I have looked into its replacement, I am using CakePHP 2.4 - Send Files http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#cake-response-file. But time I use it / make a file call it loads the whole file into the browser without my layout!

Comment: The code you've added there is kinda dangerous! You are using the `app` folder as the base, that means one could pass for example `Config/database.php` and retrieve the file contents! You should use an additional folder (one that only holds the files that should be accessible) as shown in my example.

Comment: OK, $wholePathName gets from the DB, once it checks the user is admin (therefore they can access all files) which goes to /var/www/app/DATA/CLIENT/ANY-SUB-FOLDERS-MADE - is that still wrong?

Comment: Ok I am not sure how you would be able to access the database file (but see how grate you are at folder/files within CakePHP, I will take your word for it) so should I move the DATA folder outside of the app path, e.g. for /var/www/DATA <- something like that?

Comment: I didn't knew it came from a DB, still you should make your logic secure since nothing would stop the logged in user from simply calling the image URL with a custom path fragment. Don't forget, _never trust incoming data, never ever_! In case `DATA` is always the base folder in the paths, then you should use that in the base path check, ie `mb_strpos($APPnPath, APP . 'DATA' . DS)`. ps, in [comments](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) you should use @username (for example @GlennCurtis) to ensure the one you are talking to gets notified.

Comment: After revisiting my answer so that it considers the changes made to the response class, I've noticed your modified question again, and I have removed your "solution", as it's highly unsafe. I know you said the value comes from a database, but even if that would be safe, people seeing your example may just copy it 1:1, as they don't know about your specific use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an appropriate controller/action which accepts a path fragment (passed via query for example), checks whether the current user is allowed to access files, combines the path fragment with the base path and outputs the file contents.

Then use the corresponding URLs for the `img` elements `src` attributes in your view, ie something like

```
<img src='/files/read/?file=foo/bar.jpg'>
```

That way only authorized users will be able to access your files.

Here's a very basic controller/action example, it responds with a `401` in case the user is not allowed to access the files, and with a `404` in case the file is not found, is not a file or is not within the base path, and in case everything's fine it serves the file:

```
class FilesController extends AppController
{
    public function read()
    {
        // you'd probably use auth component checks and stuff here
        if(testWhetherUserIsAllowedToAccessFiles() !== true)
        {
            throw new ForbiddenException();
        }

        // make sure that the base path points to a folder that only
        // holds the files that should be accessible!
        $base = ROOT . DS . 'files' . DS;
        $fragment = $this->request->query('file');

        // expand to a canonicalized absolute path, it's way easier to
        // test for validity using the real path
        $path = realpath($base . $fragment);

        // just a basic sanity check, you may want to implement some more
        // security checks to make sure there's really no way to access
        // files outside of the base directory! After all this is just
        // some example code.
        if(
            !!preg_match('~\.\.(\\\\|/)~', $fragment) ||
            $path === false || !is_file($path) ||
            mb_strpos($path, $base) !== 0)
        {
            throw new NotFoundException();
        }

        $this->response->file($base . $fragment);
        return $this->response;
    }
}
```

As of CakePHP 2.4.8, the response object does a check for possible path traversal fragments, so in theory, the additional checks in this example *may* not be needed, given that one does not pass the expanded, real path, but the original, concatenated one!

Comment: OK, I think I get what you have said here, but your $base line of code, is that pointing the user to the WEBROOT folder? I play around with it, many thanks, I let you know I get on. Glenn.

Comment: No, it's not pointing to the webroot, `ROOT` is the CakePHP constant for the top most folder where the `app`, `lib`, etc folders reside. Simply change it to your needs and point it to wherever you hide your files.

Comment: COOL, thanks. I play around with it and post back the complete code, once (or if?) I get it working.... Glenn.